# Structured Streaming - Foreach Sink

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I am basically reading from a Kafka source, and dumping each message through to my `foreach` processor (Thanks Jacek's page for the simple example).

If this actually works, i shall actually perform some business logic in the `process` method here, however, this doesn't work. I believe that the `println` doesn't work since its running on executors and there is no way for getting those logs back to driver.  However, this `insert into` a temp table should at least work and show me that the messages are actually consumed and processed through to the sink.

What am I missing here ?

Really looking for a second set of eyes to check my effort here:

```scala
 val stream = spark
      .readStream
      .format("kafka")
      .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", Util.getProperty("kafka10.broker")) 
      .option("subscribe", src_topic) 
      .load()

    val rec = stream.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING) as txnJson").as[(String)]

    val df = stream.selectExpr("cast (value as string) as json")

    val writer = new ForeachWriter[Row] {
      val scon = new SConConnection
      override def open(partitionId: Long, version: Long) = {
        true
      }
      override def process(value: Row) = {
        println("++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++" + value.get(0))
        scon.executeUpdate("insert into rs_kafka10(miscCol) values("+value.get(0)+")")
      }
      override def close(errorOrNull: Throwable) = {
        scon.closeConnection
      }
    }


    val yy = df.writeStream
      .queryName("ForEachQuery")
      .foreach(writer)
      .outputMode("append")
      .start()

    yy.awaitTermination()
```

Comment: what is SConConnection? The writer is serialized and send to the executors, if your `scon` is not serializable you should put the construction in the open method.
Can you try to run it with `--master local[*]` and check if you get your `println`s there?

Comment: Yeah @Harald, I did try that. I dont see any printlns or anything i put in the process call..  In comparison, i tweaked incoming message a bit and dumped resultant dataframe to console, that console sink worked just fine..

Comment: My bad, in local mode, the prinltln does show up on driver log. However, i am still waiting for a succesful attempt at getting any business logic methods called..

Comment: But if the println is called you can also place your business logic there. What is your problem exactly?

Comment: I have realized that i cant invoke my own methods from process method. if i dump my inline in process method, its getting invoked.  However, hbaseconnection not being serializable still is probelmatic. even when i am opening a connection outside process call, and closing in close call.. :(

Comment: `open` and `close` are designed to allow you managing resources on executors. Just create your connection in `open` method and close it in `close` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for comments from Harald and others, I found out a couple of things, which led me to achieve normal processing behaviour -

1. test code with local mode, yarn isnt the biggest help in debugging
2. for some reason, the process method of foreach sink doesnt allow calling other methods. When i put my business logic directly in there, it works.

hope it helps others.